# How to use hset with django-redis-cache?

Tags: django, caching, heroku, redis, django-redis

I am new in django/redis and i'm starting to familiarize with heroku redis addon. However, i can only use `set` and `get`.

When i'm trying to use other methods like `hset` , i get this error : `'RedisCache' object has no attribute`

`cache.hset('key', 'value')`

How can i manage this ?

Comment: use `get_redis_connection` http://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/#_raw_client_access

Comment: http://jazzband.github.io/django-redis/latest/#_raw_client_access