# how to use django-redis hset operation in redis cache

Tags: python, django, redis

I am using django **3.0.4** and python **3.6.9**. I have to use hset operation to set some values in redis cache.

- My try:

```
from django.core.cache import caches

cache.set(), cache.get() // these operation are working
```

But I am not able to use hset and hget operation using this library. There is no proper documentation about this in Django official docs.

Note: I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48551562/how-to-use-hset-with-django-redis-cache) (Not A copy)

Comment: I have found solution, writing own answer to help community.

Comment: Use get_redis_connection https://github.com/jazzband/django-redis#raw-client-access

Answer (score 4):

This is how I resolved the issue:

- pip install django-redis-cache (3rd party redis client)

Settings.py:

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "127.0.0.1:6379/1",
        "OPTIONS": {"CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",},
    }
}
```

In views.py ::

```
from django.core.cache import caches
redis_cache=caches['default']
redis_client=redis_cache.client.get_client()
redis_client.hset('myhash','key1', 'value1')
```

Hope this will help.
Docs: [Django-redis-cache](https://github.com/sebleier/django-redis-cache)

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
from django.core.cache import caches
cache = caches[settings.CACHE_FROM_SETTINGS]
```

To store in cache:

```
cache.hset('hash', 'key1', 'value1')
cache.hset('hash', 'key2', 'value2')
```

To fetch. specific key from specific hash:

```
cache.hget('hash', 'key1')
```

To fetch all the keys for that `hash`, use:

```
cache.hgetall('hash')
```

`hgetall` return `dict`:

```
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', ... }
```

and to delete the hash set:

```
cache.hdel(hash, 'key')
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey @Sanu Your importing line is wrong Please import cache not caches. I am surprised how are you running with "caches".

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.set("Your key", "Your dict data") 
cache.get("Your key")
```

Comment: Hello @Vaibhav As per the django 3.0 doc from::  django.core.cache import caches > this import is recommended. and my query was about to use hset and hget, usual get and set are working fine here.